# Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" when running migrate-to-git

Tags: java, git, rational-team-concert

```js
    `Create the list of baselines
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at to.rtc.cli.migrate.MigrateTo.createTagListFromBaselines(MigrateTo.java:251)
    at to.rtc.cli.migrate.MigrateTo.run(MigrateTo.java:117)
    at to.rtc.cli.migrate.git.MigrateToGit.run(MigrateToGit.java:25)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.core.AbstractSubcommand.run(AbstractSubcommand.java:51)
    at com.ibm.team.rtc.cli.infrastructure.internal.core.SubcommandLauncher.run(SubcommandLauncher.java:601)
    at com.ibm.team.rtc.cli.infrastructure.internal.core.SubcommandLauncher.doStart(SubcommandLauncher.java:370)
    at com.ibm.team.rtc.cli.infrastructure.internal.core.SubcommandLauncher.run(SubcommandLauncher.java:130)
    at com.ibm.team.rtc.cli.infrastructure.internal.Application.start(Application.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)`
```

When I try to run the command migrate-to-git, I get the above exceptions.  I am using RTC version 6.0.1. 
And followed this link to migrate https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2gitcli
If any one have idea plz help me.